# Cannot drop constraint due to FK references

Tags: postgresql, foreign-key, postgresql-9.4, constraint

I have detected a duplicate index on an id field on one of our tables, as that column is the PK, but there's also a separate UNIQUE index on such column, which is useless. But I cannot delete the UNIQUE CONSTRAINT as it is referenced by 2 FKs, as in the following messages:

```
alter table checkpoint drop constraint unique_id_checkpoint;

ERROR:  cannot drop constraint unique_id_checkpoint on table checkpoint because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  constraint fk_vehiculo_checkpoint_idpunto on table vehiculo_checkpoint depends on index unique_id_checkpoint
constraint fk_geocelda_punto on table geocelda depends on index unique_id_checkpoint
constraint fk_checkpoin_id on table ruta_checkpoint depends on index unique_id_checkpoint
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
Query failed
PostgreSQL said: cannot drop constraint unique_id_checkpoint on table checkpoint because other objects depend on it
Detail: constraint fk_vehiculo_checkpoint_idpunto on table vehiculo_checkpoint depends on index unique_id_checkpoint
constraint fk_geocelda_punto on table geocelda depends on index unique_id_checkpoint
constraint fk_checkpoin_id on table ruta_checkpoint depends on index unique_id_checkpoint
Hint: Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
```

As I've also got a FK on the same column (id), is it possible to switch those referencing FKs to the PK instead of the UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, so I can actually delete such constraint?

Comment: this may help u : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15009099/5264030

Comment: Thanks @YassineLAADIDI that actually worked, although I had to drop / recreate 3 FKS to be able to drop the CONSTRAINT needed.